# Creating separate page for news in a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have: index page of website with a section for latest news (short version with a link).

I want: the link in short news have to direct to another page with full version. For every news this page will be similar. Can I do it automatically? In WordPress I will add new post and I don't know how it will create new page of website with a link on it, using my template of this page.

Answer (score 3):

In the news template, right side of the side bar, you can select the template, usually it comes with default template,

Change it to Blog template. Then you can work on it further.
Good luck [image]